# Values not committing to persistent storage

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences, commit

Can someone please help me see what I've overlooked here?

The thing is, these values won't commit to persistent storage - `.commit()` returns true and everything, but the values are simply not there...

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (timerStarted) {
    // Save the values
            settings.edit().putInt(getString(beer).toString(), savedVal_beer);
            settings.edit().putInt(getString(lightBeer).toString(), savedVal_ltBeer);
            settings.edit().putInt(getString(strongBeer).toString(), savedVal_stBeer);
            settings.edit().putInt(getString(wine).toString(), savedVal_wine);
            settings.edit().putInt(getString(fortifiedWine).toString(), savedVal_fortWine);
            settings.edit().putInt(getString(liqeur).toString(), savedVal_liqeur);
            settings.edit().putInt(getString(spirits).toString(), savedVal_spirits);
            if (counterStarted) {
                settings.edit().putString(getString(R.string.key_counter_lastTypeUsed), selectedType);
            }
            settings.edit().commit();
            if (settings.edit().commit()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
```

I have added a breakpoint at the end and used the debugger to verify that the variables to be stored are indeed there, however when I use adb to pull the sharedPrefs xml-file, none of the values have actually been saved...

`timerStarted` and `counterStarted` are both true, as they should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use one [`edit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit%28%29) call, only. And remove the dual call to [`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29).

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(beer).toString(), savedVal_beer);
editor.putInt(getString(lightBeer).toString(), savedVal_ltBeer);
editor.putInt(getString(strongBeer).toString(), savedVal_stBeer);
editor.putInt(getString(wine).toString(), savedVal_wine);
editor.putInt(getString(fortifiedWine).toString(), savedVal_fortWine);
editor.putInt(getString(liqeur).toString(), savedVal_liqeur);
editor.putInt(getString(spirits).toString(), savedVal_spirits);
if (counterStarted) {
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.key_counter_lastTypeUsed), selectedType);
}
if (editor.commit()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Do the multiple `settings.edit()` calls interfere with eachother so nothing gets saved then? If so - then it would probably be best to define an Editor object globally for the entire class? But I don't have dual calls to `commit()`- the last one's just for checking if it was successful...

Comment: Yes, precisely; `edit()` clears the values stored in the `Editor` each time, so calling it only once is mandatory. And, if you call `commit()` twice, it evaluates twice. It will still evaluate if you put it inside `if()`s.